# Object movement as well as in the UNity3d editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Maybe you have a script to move an object, the same as in the editor UNity3d or in a store, can someone else see it? Paid or free. For example, I clicked on an object / selected a cube, and arrows appeared, and for these arrows I pull, or something like that? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a small script that fully satisfies my needs

```
    public class ClickAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{

  private Vector3 screenPoint;
  private Vector3 offset;

  void OnMouseDown()
  {
    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint
    (new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
  }

  void OnMouseDrag()
  {
    Vector3 cursorScreenPoint =
      new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
    Vector3 cursorPosition
      = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorScreenPoint) + offset;
    transform.position
      = cursorPosition;
  }

}
```